# Does anyone have a easy-to-use .png fix for IE?

Tags: jquery, iepngfix

I'm looking for an easy way to make IE accept .png images without the ugly white area where transparency areas are supposed to be.  So far I've tried several png fix packs that seem to have too many configuration settings that I can't get to work...any GOOD suggestions?

Comment: Can you specify what is wrong with JQuery plugin pngFix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jquery.andreaseberhard.de/pngFix/index.html is easy to implement. I use it on my site and can confirm it works well.